# Querying array elements with Mongo

Tags: mongodb, querying, odm

How can I query the smoothies that have apple in them? (below is a collection with 3 documents)

```
_id => 1
name => 'best smoothie' 
ingredients => Array
    (
        [0] => apple
        [1] => raspberry
        [2] => orange
        [3] => banana
    )
_id => 2
name => 'summer smoothie' 
ingredients => Array
    (
        [0] => lemon
        [1] => mint

    )
_id => 3
name => 'yogurt smoothie' 
ingredients => Array
    (
        [0] => apple
        [1] => blueberry

    )
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you simply run the below query MongoDB is smart enough to figure out what you're trying to do.

```
{ ingredients: "apple" }
```

Mongo will see that ingredients is a list and only return documents that contain "apple" some where in that list.

Answer (score -2):

From the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#comparison):

> Note: Fields containing arrays match conditional operators, **if only one
>   item matches**.
>
> Therefore, the following query:
>
> `db.collection.find( { field: { $gt:0, $lt:2 } } );`
>
> Will match a document that contains the
>   following field:
>
> `{ field: [-1,3] }`

Answer (score -6):

Why do people write scalable applications for smoothies?

db.find({"ingredients":{$in: "apple"}});

Comment: That is an invalid query.  The $in value must be an array.  For example:

```{"ingredient": {$in: ["apple","cinnamon","sugar"]}}```

Would test whether the ingredient field contains one of the 3 listed values.