# How do I find documents with an element at a particular position in an array using MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I would like to find all documents where element 0 of `ingredients` is `apple`. So I want to get document 1 and 3, but not 2. Is such a thing possible natively in Mongo?

The example as it is does not make sense, but my application was too complicated to put up here.

```
{
    _id => 1
    name => 'best smoothie' 
    ingredients => Array
        (
            [0] => apple
            [1] => raspberry
            [2] => orange
            [3] => banana
        )
}
```

```
{
    _id => 2
    name => 'summer smoothie' 
    ingredients => Array
        (
            [0] => lemon
            [1] => mint
            [2] => apple

        )
}
```

```
{
    _id => 3
    name => 'yogurt smoothie' 
    ingredients => Array
        (
            [0] => apple
            [1] => blueberry

        )
}
```

Example borrowed from - [Querying array elements with Mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308119/querying-array-elements-with-mongo).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the array positional operator ([docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/positional/)). What's useful is that you can use that same pattern and specify a specific index rather than using the general `$` syntax.

Assuming this is your data:

```
> db.so1.insert({name:"best smoothie", ingredients: ['apple','raspberry','orange','banana']})
> db.so1.insert({name:"summer smoothie", ingredients: ['lemon','mint','apple']})
> db.so1.insert({name:"yogurt smoothie", ingredients: ['apple','blueberry']})
```

If you want limit the search to only index position `0`, just add that to the array property name as shown below:

```
> db.so1.find({'ingredients.0':'apple'})
```

Results:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("51c4425ff227e278e59f5df5"),
        "name" : "best smoothie",
        "ingredients" : [
                "apple",
                "raspberry",
                "orange",
                "banana"
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("51c4428af227e278e59f5df7"),
        "name" : "yogurt smoothie",
        "ingredients" : [
                "apple",
                "blueberry"
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$unwind` with `$project` mongo functions.

```
`$unwind` - split up array
`$project` - add smth like index for each splitted element
```

after you could use simple `findOne` statement.

Comment: how do you add the index on each new documents created by the `$unwind` command ?

Comment: @Pierre-LouisGottfrois it pretty simple. `10gen` has a great tutorial about creating index fields. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

Comment: You don't need to use aggregation to do this. See [my](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17235010/95190) answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any way to achieve this using simple `array`. However here is what you could do using an array of hashes:

```
> db.collections.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51c400d2b9f10d2c26817c5f"), "ingredients" : [ { "value1" : "apple" }, { "value2" : "orange" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51c400dbb9f10d2c26817c60"), "ingredients" : [ { "value1" : "mint" }, { "value2" : "apple" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51c400e1b9f10d2c26817c61"), "ingredients" : [ { "value1" : "apple" }, { "value2" : "lemon" } ] }

> db.collections.find({ ingredients: { $elemMatch: { value1: 'apple' }}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51c400d2b9f10d2c26817c5f"), "ingredients" : [ { "value1" : "apple" }, { "value2" : "orange" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51c400e1b9f10d2c26817c61"), "ingredients" : [ { "value1" : "apple" }, { "value2" : "lemon" } ] }
```

Comment: Actually, there is a way that works well in this situation. See my answer.